# `elif' unexpected.. for Date function

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

Here is my code

```
CURR_MNTH=$(date +'%m' -d 'now')

if [$CURR_MNTH < 04]
    THIS_QTR=1
elif [$CURR_MNTH < 07] && [$CURR_MNTH > 03]
    THIS_QTR=2
elif [$CURR_MNTH < 10] && [$CURR_MNTH > 07]
    THIS_QTR=3
elif [$CURR_MNTH > 09]
    THIS_QTR=4
fi

echo $THIS_QTR
```

I am trying to get the current quarter with the above logic, but the prompt says that i have `elif' unexpected error.. Can someone please help me

Comment: See http://www.shellcheck.net/.

Comment: #!/bin/ksh   I am using k-shell

Comment: temp change to #!/bin/bash, you'll get correct guidance from shellcheck.net. Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

Provided that you use Bash, there are numerous errors:

- no semicolons after the `if` statements;
- no spaces between brackets and conditional expressions;
- conjunctions should be given inside the same set of brackets;
- consider using `-lt` and `-gt` for value tests.

The correct code would look like this:

```
CURR_MNTH=$(date +'%m' -d 'now')

if [[ $CURR_MNTH -lt 4 ]]; then
    THIS_QTR=1
elif [[ $CURR_MNTH -lt 7 && $CURR_MNTH -gt 3 ]]; then
    THIS_QTR=2
elif [[ $CURR_MNTH -lt 10 && $CURR_MNTH -gt 7 ]]; then
    THIS_QTR=3
elif [[ $CURR_MNTH -gt 9 ]]; then
    THIS_QTR=4
fi

echo $THIS_QTR
```

Consider running http://www.shellcheck.net/ on your code next time.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the quarter from the month by a formula:

```
THIS_QTR=$(( 1 + (10#$CURR_MNTH - 1) / 3))
```

The `10#` prefix indicates decimal number, thus preventing the leading 0 to be interpreted as octal number indicator.

Comment: after i ran the command i am getting 1, but which should be 2

Comment: @Dileep: I tested it with `for CURR_MNTH in {0{1..9},1{0..2}} ; do echo $CURR_MNTH $(( 1 + (10#$CURR_MNTH - 1) / 3)) ; done`. (Note that your code gives no answer for `07`).